# default_time_zone not recognised by MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to set the GLOBAL time of my MariaDB database to UTC. I've followed the recommendations of their official documentation and `default_time_zone="+00:00"` in the my.cnf file, however it does NOT work and I get the following error when I start it in the shell: `mysql: unknown variable 'default_time_zone=+00:00'`.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Your quotes seem wrong. Don't quote the whole line but just the value: `default_time_zone = '+00:00'`

Comment: the quotes are fine, I miswrote my post :) I'll edit now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the quotes
2. As the error message states command line client (mysql) complains about unknown variable, since default_time_zone is a server but not a client variable. So you added it in wrong section. Move the entry to the server section:

[server]

default_time_zone=+00:00